# How to make an async method to handle data from delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, delegates

I use btstack to communicate between my iPhone and an external device. I want to send a special command to retrieve the device's special data. But I could only obtain the data from btstack's handlePacket: method . I could only handle the data using delegate.
But I want to make a method like this:

```
- (void)readDataAsyncWithCompletionHandler:(Handler)handler
```

The handler block should obtain the data. 
I don't know how to do .
I made a Command class to do the command construction and sending.

I know we can use await in c#! So how to deal with it in ios?

Comment: You should add, how you currently use the delegate approach. It's impossible to propose a workable solution when important details are omitted.

Answer (score 2):

You should write like this.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    //do you time consuming task


   dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       //if you are doing any interaction with UI, do it here

   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use Grand Central Dispatch in such situations. [Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial) is a beginner-friendly tutorial and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) is the official Apple documentation on GCD.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(theMethod) withObject:nil];
```

or create an NSInvocationOperation object.

```
NSInvocationOperation operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(theMethod) object:nil];
```

and add it to the NSOperationQueue.

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
    [queue addOperation:operation];
```

or create a dispatch_async block as given above.